# How do I prevent multiple clicks on an API endpoint server side?

Tags: express, session, rate-limiting

I have an API endpoint, and I'm curious if there is a way to prevent the user from accessing this endpoint many times rapidly. I have access to `express.sesssion` as a store, as well as the payload that they are submitting. Ideally, I would be able to store the payload, and if that same payload appears once, I allow it, then again, It would have to "cooldown" before accepting that second request.

I know of course that I can disable the button, but I am just curious how to rate-limit a function (endpoint) like this, 1 request every 3 seconds.

Comment: Look up "rate limiting".  Lots of solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

use [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)

it lets you limit requsts from single ip

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);

// only apply to requests that begin with /api/
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);
```